# Expand single quotes in a Net::HTTP variable?

Tags: ruby

I am using Net::HTTP to get a request from a Google API with a custom header:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, {'Authorization' => 'GoogleLogin auth=#{auth}'})
```

The `#{auth}` is a variable that changes each time I run the program, so I made a variable with it, but the single quotes don't expand it. I can't change the single quotes to double quotes, because Google only accepts the header with single quotes.

Is there any way to expand the variable but keep the single quotes?

Comment: The quotes are part of your Ruby program.  How can Google know or care about them? It just receives an HTTP header containing the string.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's the only conclusion I could come to. When I replace #{auth} with the current auth token, it works fine. But when I put in the variable, it fails. When I change the single quotes to double quotes in both sides of the header, it fails too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I can't change the single quotes to double quotes, because google only accepts the header with single quotes.

So hard to believe it.

Anyway, try [`Kernel%sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) or its shorter version just `str % [arguments..]`. It will help.